DataNucleus for RDBMS Setup Issue: Meta-Data Not Enhanced or Multiple Persistence API JARs in CLASSPATH
What is the correct way to use Datanucleus for RDBMS (Database)?
My project setup is throwing this error:
SEVERE: Found Meta-Data for class org.example.core.project.model.Project but this class is either not enhanced or you have multiple copies of the persistence API jar in your CLASSPATH!! Make sure all persistable classes are enhanced before running DataNucleus and/or the CLASSPATH is correct.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Found Meta-Data for class org.example.core.project.model.Project but this class is either not enhanced or you have multiple copies of the persistence API jar in your CLASSPATH!! Make sure all persistable classes are enhanced before running DataNucleus and/or the CLASSPATH is correct.
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.initialiseClassMetaData(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2713)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.initialiseFileMetaData(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2647)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:1361)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:1124)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialiseNucleusContext(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:921)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialise(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:513)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<init>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:417)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:104)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at org.example.SubscriptionRepositoryTest.setUp(SubscriptionRepositoryTest.java:27)

My project have dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa-query</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0-release</version>
</dependency>

And the plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

